# Oracle unions in the wrong order

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to understand why my query is returning things in a different order than I expect.
My query is:

```
SELECT 'PRINTJOBID', MAX(PRINTJOBID), null, null FROM PRINTJOB
UNION
SELECT 'AUTOID', null, MAX(AUTOID), null FROM PRINTJOBSHELLS
UNION
SELECT 'PROCESSLOGID', null, null, MAX(PROCESSLOGID) FROM PROCESSLOG;
```

I am expecting it to give me 3 rows, with printjobid at the top, followed by autoid, and then at the bottom should be processlogid. However, when I run the query I get autoid at the top, printjobid in the middle, and processlog at the bottom, like this:

AUTOID  null 771426 null
PRINTJOBID  76401 null, null
PROCESSLOGID    null null   1218693

I have tried googling about Unions being in the wrong order, and I tried searching questions on SO. I didn't see anything that seemed relevant. Is my understanding of how UNION works faulty? I thought that the query would return the rows in the order I put the select statements. Thank you!

Comment: *I thought that the query would return the rows in the order I put the select statements* -- no, not at all. The resulting order is not specified unless you specify it. Even exactly same query, being run on exactly same dataset twice in a row, can return records in different order: for instance if the database engine decides to run the queries in parallel and one of the CPU gets busy with some other task. You can't rely on any order unless you have an ORDER BY at the end of your statement.

Comment: I see, thank you for clearing that up. I'll have to use ORDER BY more often then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you can't rely on a query returning results in any special order unless you explicitly specify it in the query.

Use this:

```
SELECT  title, v1, v2, v3
FROM    (
        SELECT  'PRINTJOBID' title, MAX(PRINTJOBID) v1, null v2, null v3, 1 AS o
        FROM    PRINTJOB
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'AUTOID' title, null, MAX(AUTOID), null, 2 AS o
        FROM    PRINTJOBSHELLS
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'PROCESSLOGID' title, null, null, MAX(PROCESSLOGID), 3 AS o
        FROM    PROCESSLOG
        )
ORDER BY
        o
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want ordering of results, you need to specify an ORDER BY clause. Otherwise you are relying on implementation-specific behaviour. In this case it is probably lucky you did not get the ordering you hoped for originally, as the behaviour could easily change in future, so you need to explicitly specify ordering if it is important to you.

Comment: Ohh, so it looks like it is ordering it by the first column alphabetically by default. Is there a way for me to say don't order the results, just give me the unions in the order that you got them?